# How to display a tiled image created with gdal2Tiles in Openlayers 3?

Tags: openlayers-3, gdal

I used gdal2tiles to tile an image using default settings.

I have it displaying in OpenLayers 3 as you can see in the code snippets below, but what I can't figure out is how to programmatically determine the center. The value [-5200000, -16460000] was just manually entered for the center, but should be able to be calculated by transforming the photoHeight/2 and photoWidth/2 or transforming the image extent or something along those lines.

Or am I going about this entirely wrong?

```js
var photoHeight = 5858;
var photoWidth = 24260;
var extent = [0, 0, 24260, 5858]; //??

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                url: 'http://dev.gregwacker.com/photoAlbums/ThePanoramas/tiles/monument_valley_pano_2__10_Photos_/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png',
                wrapX: false
            })
        })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [-5200000, -16460000],
        maxZoom: 7,
        zoom: 2
    })
});
```

```css
html, body {
    background-color: #6a6a6a;
    background-image: url(http://dev.gregwacker.com/img/noise.png);
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

#map {
    background: url(http://dev.gregwacker.com/img/grid.png) repeat;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```